# Programatically add a wifi network on the BlackBerry

Tags: api, blackberry, wifi

As opposed to manually setting up a Wifi network(scanning>adding>set encryption settings, etc) I'm trying to create an app that once the user enters his login credentials will automatically add the wifi network complete with the necessary network settings.

Maybe i've been searching using the wrong keywords but I havent stumbled upon anything about this.

I'm wondering which class(es) I should be looking at. Is this even allowed by the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [HotspotClient](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/wlan/hotspot/HotspotClient.html) and [HotspotClientRegistry](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/wlan/hotspot/HotspotClientRegistry.html).